# How do you say ‘cavitation’ in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word ‘[cavitation](http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/vorto-cavitation.html)’ does not appear in Wells, nor in ReVo, nor in Sonja. It does occur in Benson and Vikivortaro. However, Benson gives ‘kaviĝ(ad)o’, while Vikivortaro gives ‘kavitacio’. However, PIV does not recognize ‘kavitacio’, but PIV is perpetually a little behind the times, is it not? So, should be go with Benson, or Vikivortaro, or something else?

edit: I neglected to check Vikipedio. I see that it has 'kavitacio', so maybe that is the way to go, after all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cavitation) linked in you question, *cavitation* has two different meanings.

As they are not so close, I would prefer to translate them with two words in Esperanto.

For the first, technical meaning ("formation of partial vacuums in a liquid") I'd prefer the internationalism *kavitacio*, but the second, medicinal meaning ("formation of cavities in an organ") translates neatly to *kaviĝo*.

Comment: I tried to correct the spelling of 'definition', but the system said my edit was too short.

Comment: I've linked to your answer: http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/vorto-cavitation.html